# Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”) firefox webextensions

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).

Get this error to in console when trying to add onclick event to button in sidebar

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>

<body>
  <div id = "content"></div>
  <script src="panel.js"></script>
<button id="createNewInstance" onclick="openDb()">New Category</button>
</body>

</html>
```

why is that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use inline scripts or define event handlers in WebExtension pages. You have to add your event handler in an external JavaScript file.

*panel.js*

```
document.getElementById("createNewInstance").addEventListener("click", openDb)
```

Comment: It says : TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

function openDb() {
    console.log("openDb ...");
     }


document.getElementById("createNewInstance").addEventListener("click", openDb);


// const contentBox = document.querySelector("#createNewInstance");
//var createNewInstanceEl = window.document.getElementById("createNewInstance");
// createNewInstanceEl.onclick = openDb();

Comment: The null error occurs because `<script src="panel.js"></script>`
needs to come *after* `<button id=...`.